# Weird c++ code snippet

Tags: c++

I have this snippet:

```
template<class T>
class VECTOR_2D 
{
public:
    T x,y;

    VECTOR_2D() 
        :x(T()),y(T())
    {}
}
```

What are x and y initialized to in the constructor?

Comment: unwind's answer is correct, and by the way, it is unnecessary to include x and y in the initializer list of VECTOR_2D's constructor list like this, as they would automatically be initialized by their default constructor.

Comment: @DataGraham: You're wrong. If `T` is a primitive, and you don't explicitly initialise them, they will remain uninitialised.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, you are correct, primitives would be uninitialized, but would initializing them with "T()" as above have any effect?

Comment: @DataGraham : Yes, that would zero-initialize them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x` and `y` are *copy-initialized* to `T`'s *value-initialized* value.

From the C++03 standard, §8.5/7:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.

And from §8.5/5:

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a class type with a user-declared constructor, then the default constructor for `T` is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if `T` has no accessible default constructor);
> - if `T` is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of `T` is value-initialized;
> - if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized
>
> To *zero-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a scalar type, the object is set to the value of `0` (zero) converted to `T`;
> - if `T` is a non-union class type, each nonstatic data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized;
> - if `T` is a union type, the object’s first named data member) is zero-initialized;
> - if `T` is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
> - if `T` is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

---

`x(T()),y(T())` could be replaced with `x(),y()` to instead value-initialize `x` and `y` directly. In most circumstances this will achieve the same net effect (assuming `T` is copy constructable), but in some cases this will be more efficient, so as a general rule this approach should always be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

An instance (each) of `T`, built by that type's [default constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor).

Comment: I'd add "`x(), y()` would be mostly equivalent; the copy will be optimised out."

Comment: is T is the int type, how are they initialized?

Comment: @DisplayName: `(int() == 0) == true`

Comment: @Tomalak: The difference is that in the code in the question, access to the copy-constructor of `T` is required, even if it is not used. I.e. if the copy constructor is deleted (C++0x) or if it private from this context), the code in the question will fail, while `x(), y()` will compile --probably more of a feature than a problem if you ask me...

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal : David is correct, and that code is irrelevant. [This code](http://www.ideone.com/qoh0c) is pertinent.

Comment: @ildjarn: Right, using the copy constructor requires the copy constructor to be accessible. True. [I had missed the word "copy".]

Answer (score 2):

Someone's not realised that you can default-initialise like this:

```
VECTOR_2D() : x(), y() {};
```

So, instead, they're being *really verbose* by doing something that's a bit like this:

```
X x = X();
```

The pointless copy should be optimised out by any sane compiler, but it's still a bit daft.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `T()` in an expression creates an rvalue of type `T` and *value-initializes* it.

If `T` has a default constructor that constructor will be called, if `T` is an aggregate type, each one of the attributes will be *value-initialized*, for *primitive* types (using *primitive* in the Java sense: integer, float, double, char, pointers), they will be set to 0.