# C++ standard: default "const T& value" in vector constructor for type 'int'

Tags: c++, stl

```
explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );

vector<int> vec(10);
cout << "vec.size: " << vec.size() << endl;
for (vector<int>::const_iterator iter=vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter)
{
    cout << *iter << endl;
}
```

Output from VS2010:

```
vec.size: 10
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Question>: 
Based on the latest C++ standard, what is the default int value when we define an object of vector by using vectorObject(size_type)?

Here as you can see, VS2010 outputs 0 as the default int value. But I don't know whether or not this is required by C++ standard.

Comment: I will let the language lawyers bring the difference between value-initialization, default-initialization and zero-initialization. But rest assured that `T()` yields zero when `T` is a primitive numeric type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is the required behavior.  `T()` for any numeric type `T` yields `0` (of type `T`, of course).

This is called *value initialization*, which for numeric types is the same as *zero initialization*.

Comment: Usefully, that's also supposed to work for *arrays* of numeric types, `T x[7]();`.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950144/weird-c-code-snippet/5950176#5950176) for the full standardese.